# Facebook sharing in android app + review submission

Tags: android, facebook, sharing

I'm going crazy.
I needed a simple facebook sharing feature in my android app, where a user can share some text and an image that is saved in the app.
After figuring out that using an intent is not helpful in this case, I started using the Facebook SDK. 
After already spending to much time with this, I can finally share a picture, when I run the app directly from Android Studio on the device. So all the facebook application id and content provider setup works fine.
Finally, I created an .apk and tested it. In this case, the sharing ist not working. The sharing dialog appears and disappears after 2 seconds by itself.
After searching for possible answers, I logged in to my facebook developer account and changed the following setting: 
[image: Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?-setting]

But this didn't help. 
Finally, I saw in my facebook developer account that I can submit the app for approval:

[image: submit the app for approval]

But I`m wondering, why I should do that for a simple sharing feature. Does anybody know, if the submission process of facebook is needed for this case? 
I'm grateful for any help.
Here is my code for sharing (like I said, it all works fine and I'm able to share the image, when I run the app directly from Android Studio):

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {

            OpenGraphObject recipe = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("my_namespace:object");
            recipe.setProperty("title", getResources().getString(R.string.share_title));
            recipe.setProperty("description", getResources().getString(R.string.share_text));
            recipe.setProperty("og:image", getImageContentPathForRecipeUri(mRecipe.getImageUri()));

            OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
            action.setType("og.likes");
            action.setProperty("object", recipe);

            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "object")
                    .setFragment(this)
                    .build();
            facebookUIHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

        }
```

Comment: check this out..https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Answer (score 1):

You would need to submit for a review in order to use the publish_actions permission. If you're using a share dialog to post to Facebook, you would not need to post to Facebook. In addition, pre-filling text where a person would usually type out a message is not allowed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the [Facebook SDK share function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/overview). It doesn't need additional permissions and submit it to Facebook for reviewing.

Just click the mode and switch it to online. The share function works properly!

[image]